# How to make a method taking unknown amount of values?

Tags: c#, function, return-value, subroutine

To explain the question on a simple example, let's say:

I have a method which takes the average of two numbers:

```
private double TakeAverage(double n1,double n2) 
{
    average = (number1 + number2) / 2.0000;
    return average;
}
```

And I call it like:

```
textBox3.Text = (TakeAverage(number1, number2)).ToString();
```

Q1:

How to make this function able to run **without calling it multiple times** like:

```
TakeAverage(number1, number2, number3, number4, number5)  // as wanted number of times...
```

Q2:how to make this function changing return value by number of values which it takes?

For example

```
Substring(1) //if it takes just one value, it returns all the chars after first char but
Substring(1,2)//if it takes two values, it returns 2 characters after first char
```

Comment: If you have two questions then create two questions please. Asking two questions in one is confusing.

Comment: Totally right but the reason was, I thought there are many common situations, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

```
public double TakeAverage(params double[] numbers)
{
  double result = 0.0;

  if (numbers != null && numbers.Length > 0)
    result = numbers.Average();

  return result;
}
```

As `params` allows the client to send nothing, we should test whether `numbers` exists and has items.

Usage:

```
double average = TakeAverage(1, 2, 3, 4.4);     //2.6
double anotherAverage = TakeAverage();          //0
double yetAnotherAverage = TakeAverage(null);   //0
```

---

UPDATE

Based on your comments, I understand that you're looking for something that's called **overload**: you want that a given method behaves differently based on its arguments.

I'll give an example, you must modify it to suit your needs.

Let's pretend that, besides our original `TakeAverage` method, we want another one that does an average and multiplies it for a given number. It would be something like:

```
public double TakeAverage(int factor, params double[] numbers)
{
  double result = 0.0;

  if (numbers != null && numbers.Length > 0)
    result = numbers.Average() * factor;

  return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
double average = TakeAverage(1.0, 2, 3, 4.4);     //2.6
double notAnAverage = TakeAverage(1, 2, 3, 4.4);  //3.1333...
```

Note that I had to explicitly say that the first number is a `double` (`1.0`), otherwise it would fall on the second overload and multiply it.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov you're right, I hadn't noticed it! Updated the answer, thanks

Comment: First, thanks. But we already had a function Average() and that makes everything is simpler on this simple example. What can we do if we have to make this manually, without instant funtions? I mean we may have to repeat this subroutine number of times..

Comment: @letheanhypnone I'm sorry, but I don't understand your use case. I thought it was about the different set of numbers to compute the average, but there seems to be another point here. Could you explain better?

Comment: You might consider TakeAverage(double, params double[]) to ensure there is always one.

Comment: @Andre Calil I want to use this construction in many areas. Your answer solves my first question, but generally we may have not functions like Average an may have to change the content of subroutine as the number of parameters we get. Think a situation we have to divide total by 2 or by 200 or Substring example. It runs a block if it has one parameters and it runs another if it has 2 parameters. Sorry my english may not be enough to tell what i think.

Comment: @letheanhypnone Now I understand. Do you have a known set of `possibilities`? For example, with 1 number will run code block A; with 2 numbers, B; with 3 numbers, C...

Comment: Exactly:).If we collapse two questions, on this example: TakeAverage(double,double,...) will take the average of all. TakeAverage(int, double,double,...) will take take average of doubles and multiply the result by int at first. This is a made up example but if it's solved, my problem is solved. I correct it for my needs. [we dont know how many parameters in both situations] Thanks:)

Comment: Does this make error if it doesn't starts with integer or not? Because at start integer may or not exists.

Comment: @letheanhypnone No, there won't be an error, the runtime will call the first method (the original `TakeAverage`)

Answer (score 1):

There is the `params`-keyword where you can say that you take a not-specified amount of arguments.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The params keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments.
>
> You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration, or an array of arguments of the specified type. You also can send no arguments.
>
> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a method declaration.

Example:

```
private double TakeAverage(params double[] numbers) 
{
     double average = 0.0;
     if(numbers != null && numbers.Length > 0){
     foreach(double d in numbers)
          average += d;
     average /= numbers.Length;
     }
     return average;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to your substring function question.

If you specify one argument, sub string(5) for example, it will return all the characters AFTER the 5th character in the string.
if I have the string "elephant", it would return "ant".

If I add a second argument to the function, it will start at the first given argument, as above, and go on x amount of characters before stopping.
if we use the above example string, "elephant" and do sub string(5,1) it would return "a".

(a good way to work this out is to add both numbers, that will be the last character in your string!)

What I'm asking it to do is create a new string going from the 5th character in the given string, and for my new string to be 1 character long.

This is because the string class has overloaded the sub-string method.

See here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.71).aspx